# how to remove non 'ui-*' words by invoking str.replace() with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript,

```
str = 'left ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content center right';
```

Is it possible to remove non 'ui-*' words by invoking str.replace() with regexp ?

The result after invoking str.replace() should be:

```
str.replace(/ /, '') = 'ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content';
```

I've tried some regexp patterns, but they doesn't work.

Comment: The pattern I tried was :

/\b(?!ui-)[\S]+\b/g

but it didn't work since "\b" would also treat "-" as a word boundry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could try something like:

```
str.match(/ui-[\w-]+/g).join(" ")
```

Comment: Works fine. However there is an assumption that the words in the original string are split by a single space. If that were not true, the join() result won't be the same as that which the user expects after removing the non 'ui-' words.

Comment: This assumption seems appropriate being that `str` in this example is likely the contents of some DOM node's `className` attribute, and that Kieran is looking to do some unobtrusive widget configuration via that attribute.

Comment: @Vijay Dev: that's right, but it really doesn't matter. those are class names. some are jquery ui classes. joining on a single space achieves the same result. and if you look at what the asker wants, this achieves it quite well.

Comment: @Justin, @George: Agreed. The context of the usage makes the whitespaces irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be a regex?  You *could* do it this way, but split/join seems like a better candidate here.